# JavaScript Independent Modules

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, observer-pattern, factory-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I have several modules in my application and some global variables. One module may require some methods from other modules to work and also some global variables.

How can I organise my code so **modules won't use methods from other modules or global variables**?

```
//global variables needed in both of the modules.
var a, b;

//VIDEO MODULE
var VIDEO = (function() {

    //requires a method from USER MODULE:
    if(USER.has_liked_video()) {
        //do smth.
    }

    //requires some global variables

    return {}
})();

//USER MODULE
var USER = (function() {

    //requires a method from VIDEO MODULE:
    if(VIDEO.exists()) {
        //do smth.
    }

    //requires some global variables

    return {}
})();
```

Comment: Why don't you use a 3rd module, which would combine the functionality?

Comment: @Vidul I have thought of this but I want to know if there is a better approach?

Comment: Any global var dependency is an anti-pattern (except constants). Although not sure about the concrete requirements, my recommendation is [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) because it looks like [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Eventually any program needs refactoring; the sooner the better.

Comment: @Vidul So I should create another module to encapsulate my global variables and call methods from other modules so there are no global variables and modules will be not depending on other modules?

Comment: Ideally there should not be any global variables. I guess that you could comparatively easy replace them with objects and their corresponding [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) methods. Another way would be refactoring the two modules into one (again, the "common base" like global vars is code smell - one simple solution is a shared prototype where `B.prototype = A.prototype` and `A.prototype` contains all members (properties and methods)).

Comment: @Vidul ok I understood that there should be no global vars. What about modules calling methods from other modules? Is this bad? Should I make modules completely independent from other modules?

Comment: It depends on the design. Generally speaking, yes, modules should be totally independent / encapsulated (after all that's their purpose). Modules are just the building blocks, and as such they should not depend on anything outside them.

Comment: @Vidul ok thanks for your answers. :)

Comment: My pleasure :) [This](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleResponsibilityPrinciple) is probably much better definition than my statements.